# Prolog: List = List + Tail

Tags: list, prolog

At the moment, I am doing the following:

```
append(List, [A], AppendedList),
append(List, [B], AppendedList2)
```

Surely there is a better way, in which I can just update List?

Comment: If you want to append a single element (or any list for that matter) to the end of another list, what's wrong with using `append`? And if you want to append both `A` and `B`, then just use `append(List, [A,B], AppendedList)`. Or do you really mean that `A` and `B` are lists? If that's the case, then `[A]` and `[B]` are the wrong syntax.

Comment: I would like the result to be in List,  not AppendedList

Comment: You cannot modify a fully instantiated variable in Prolog within a predicate clause without backtracking. That applies specifically also to lists. Depending upon your broader application, you might be able to utilize *difference lists* which have an open, variable tail.